# A collection view with multiple prototype cells and a generic way of handling them under MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uicollectionview

We are currently establishing the architecture for a project and I have difficulty visualising a complete solution for this issue.
So we currently have a collection view with multiple dynamic prototypes and we subclass one of them for each cell. I was wondering if there's a way we could do something along the lines of

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: viewModel.reuseIdentifierForIndexPath(indexPath), for: indexPath)
    //update cell here in a generic way based on the class of this cell (we have this information)
    return cell
}
```

Basically, we want to avoid doing things like

```
if indexPath.row == 0 { 
//do stuff for this specific cell 
}
```

inside methods like collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) / collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:), while also complying to the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MVVM pattern for the cells themselves. So each cell is going to have its own viewModel. Then you can use something like the code below:

```
class ViewModel {

    func reuseIdentifier(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> String {
        //...
    }

    func cellViewModel(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> BaseCellViewModel {
        //...
    }

}

class BaseCellViewModel {
    //...
}

class CellAViewModel: BaseCellViewModel {
    //...
}

class CellBViewModel: BaseCellViewModel {
    //...
}

class CellA: UICollectionViewCell {
    var viewModel: CellAViewModel! {
        didSet {
            //update UI
        }
    }
}

class CellB: UICollectionViewCell {
    var viewModel: CellBViewModel! {
        didSet {
            //update UI
        }
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //...

    var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let reuseIdentifier = viewModel.reuseIdentifier(for: indexPath)
        let cell =
        collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        //update cell here in a generic way based on the class of this cell (we have this information)
        configure(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func configure(cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch cell {
        case let cell as CellA:
            cell.viewModel = viewModel.cellViewModel(for: indexPath) as! CellAViewModel
        case let cell as CellB:
            cell.viewModel = viewModel.cellViewModel(for: indexPath) as! CellBViewModel
        default:
            fatalError("Unkown cell type")
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: The thing is, shouldn't cell (which is a view) be decoupled from the viewModel entirely ?

Comment: @PavalacheAlexandru You can also use a protocol based approach and make your viewModels implement the protocol so that your cells/viewControllers depend on the protocol, not the class implementation (useful for mocking). But that can add a lot of complexity to the code and it may or may not be useful depending on the needs of your app.

Comment: @PavalacheAlexandru if you decouple everything, and you later want to add a label to your cell, you'll have to change a lot of classes: viewModel protocol, the viewModel implementation, the tests, the mock viewModels, etc...